# Crawler script runs without error, but there's no output excel as I expected

Tags: python

I tried to crawl some housing information from a Chinese housing website. The code has no error when I run. However there's no output file when the running process completes.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import os
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from parsel import Selector
import re

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 BIDUBrowser/8.7 Safari/537.36'
}


def catchHouseList(url):
    resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True)
    if resp.status_code == 200:
        reg = re.compile('<li.*?class="clear">.*?<a.*?class="img.*?".*?href="(.*?)"')
        urls = re.findall(reg, resp.text)
        return urls
    return []
def catchHouseDetail(url):
    resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(url)
    if resp.status_code == 200:
        info = {}
        soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')
        info['Title'] = soup.select('.main')[0].text
        info['Total_Price'] = soup.select('.total')[0].text
        info['Unit_Price'] = soup.select('.unit')[0].text
        info['Price_per_square'] = soup.select('.unitPriceValue')[0].text
        # p = soup.select('.tax')
        # info['Reference_price'] = soup.select('.tax')[0].text
        info['Built_time'] = soup.select('.subInfo')[2].text
        info['Place_Name'] = soup.select('.info')[0].text
        info['Area'] = soup.select('.info a')[0].text + ':' + soup.select('.info a')[1].text
        info['Lianjia_number'] = str(url)[34:].rsplit('.html')[0]
        info['flooring_plan'] = str(soup.select('.content')[2].select('.label')[0].next_sibling)
        info['floor'] = soup.select('.content')[2].select('.label')[1].next_sibling
        info['Area_Size'] = soup.select('.content')[2].select('.label')[2].next_sibling
        info['Flooring_structure'] = soup.select('.content')[2].select('.label')[3].next_sibling
        info['Inner_Area'] = soup.select('.content')[2].select('.label')[4].next_sibling
        info['Building_Category'] = soup.select('.content')[2].select('.label')[5].next_sibling
        info['House_Direction'] = soup.select('.content')[2].select('.label')[6].next_sibling
        info['Building_Structure'] = soup.select('.content')[2].select('.label')[7].next_sibling
        info['Decoration'] = soup.select('.content')[2].select('.label')[8].next_sibling
        info['Stair_Number'] = soup.select('.content')[2].select('.label')[9].next_sibling
        info['Heating'] = soup.select('.content')[2].select('.label')[10].next_sibling
        info['Elevator'] = soup.select('.content')[2].select('.label')[11].next_sibling
        #  info['Aseest_Year'] = str(soup.select('.content')[2].select('.label')[12].next_sibling)
        return info
    pass


def appendToXlsx(info):
    fileName = './second_hand_houses.xlsx'
    dfNew = pd.DataFrame([info])
    if (os.path.exists(fileName)):
        sheet = pd.read_excel(fileName)
        dfOld = pd.DataFrame(sheet)
        df = pd.concat([dfOld, dfNew])
        df.to_excel(fileName)
    else:
        dfNew.to_excel(fileName)


def catch():
    pages = ['https://zs.lianjia.com/ershoufang/guzhenzhen/pg{}/'.format(x) for x in range(1, 21)]
    for page in pages:
        print(page)
        houseListURLs = catchHouseList(page)
        for houseDetailUrl in houseListURLs:
            try:
                info = catchHouseDetail(houseDetailUrl)
                appendToXlsx(info)
            except:
                pass
            time.sleep(2)

    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    catch()
```

I expected to have an excel output, but there's nothing in the end. Only telling me that the Process finished with exit code 0.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Does the xlsx module in question auto-save? Do you need to call a save function? Thank you so much if you could perhaps clarify this. Also, do you have a short version of the code that demonstrates the problem? This is called a [mcve]. Thank you!

Comment: Your script needs better error handling / logging.
catchHouselist() returns an empty list, and then there's nothing for your script to do so it exits without errors.

Comment: @AmirAlmusawi, I just learned how to program newly. Can you explain what do you mean by better error handling & logging in catchHouselist(url)?

Comment: Absolutely. Welcome to programming and to stackoverflow. I suggest you add some print statements so that you know what's happening. In your catchHouseList function, you're making a GET request, and checking for a 200 response code. If you don't get a 200 response code, then the function returns an empty list. This would be a good place to print the response code, and begin your debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one of your problem areas, with a little rewrite to help you see it. You were returning an empty list when that status code was anything other than 200, without any warning or explanation. The rest of your script requires a list to continue running. When you return an empty list, it exits cleanly.

Now, when you run your code, this function is going to return None when the server response isn't 200, and then a TypeError is going to be raised in your catch() function, which will require further error handling.

```
def catchHouseList(url):
    try:
        resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True)
        if resp.status_code == 200:
            reg = re.compile(
                '<li.*?class="clear">.*?<a.*?class="img.*?".*?href="(.*?)"')
            urls = re.findall(reg, resp.text)
            return urls
        else:
            print('catchHouseList response code:', resp.status_code)

    except Exception as e:
        print('catchHouseList:', e)
```